# Combining two notebooks

Tags: programming, dynamic, export, manipulate

I have a notebook which contain all the variables and defined functions. I want to do two tasks. As an example, I want to find the density and energy which have equations in terms of above mentioned variables and functions. If I write one code for these two tasks, it is a very large notebook. So, if I have separate notebooks for "variables and functions",density and energy, how can I connect each notebook so that they can run properly and give the result?
Could anyone please help me to do this?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the nature of your"variables and functions"?  How huge are we talking?  You might be able to place them in a .m file and read that in.  Or you might be able to place them in an initialization cell in a separate (collapsed) section in the same notebook.  A little more information might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open and evaluate the 'functions and variables' notebook and then evaluate the second (or third or fourth) notebook everything should work fine. You can use `Names[$Context <> "*"]` to see what variables and functions have been defined in the current session.

E.g:

```
In[1]:= 
a = blah;
b = blah;
c = blah;

{a, b, c}

Out[4]= {blah, blah, blah}

In[5]:= Names[$Context <> "*"]

Out[5]= {"a", "b", "blah", "c"}
```

More detail [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/VariablesAndFunctions.html).

Comment: @TMH you're welcome.